# Error while retrieving Volume data from Yahoo

Tags: r, yahoo, finance

I am trying to retrieve the volume from yahoo by creating a function (that I can later apply to a list of stocks). 
    `RetrieveVolume <- function(x){
    volume_Ind2 <- getQuote(x, src = "yahoo", "v")
    volume_Ind2 <- as.data.frame(volume_Ind2)
    volume_Ind2$Qposix <- NULL
    volume_Ind2 <- volume$sq...3.NCOL.sq..
    }`

When I try using the formula for 0001.HK for example,

```
RetrieveVolume("0001.HK")
```

I get the following:

```
Error in RetrieveVolume("0001.HK") : object 'volume' not found
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here:

- you're calling a variable `volume` which is not defined yet.
- you do not return any value through your function

a quick solution to the problem will be

```
RetrieveVolume <- function(x){
   volume_Ind2 <- getQuote(x, src = "yahoo", "v")
   return(volume_Ind2[,2])
}
```

or a simpler solution would be

```
RetrieveVolume <- function(x){
   return(getQuote(x, what=yahooQF("Volume"))[,"Volume"])
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian, applied and it works perfectly fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, if I answered your question well enough, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer. You're not obligated to though! @Pino

Comment: Hi, I click on the mark, but i am too new to the system. it wont validate it